# Add load more button to listview in android

Tags: android

I am working on android projects. In my application I am getting the data from php webservice. I added my data to different arraylists and set them to listadapter. But my problem is it is taking very long time to display the data in list. Hence now I want to display first 10 items and want to keep a loadmore button at the bottom of the screen. Once the load more button is clicked the next 10 items need to display. Please can anybody help me in this regard. I would really appreciate for this help.
Thank you in advance.

Code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main1);

        Longop op = new Longop();
            op.execute("");
    }


public void loadSomeDummyData() {

        try {

            response = CustomHttpClient
                    .executeHttpPost(
                            "http://website.com/folder/testfile.php",
                            postParameters);

            for (int i = 1; i < arr1.length - 1; i++) {

                id.add(new String(arr[0]));
                name.add(new String(arr[1]));
                dateofbirth.add(new String(arr[2]));
                status.add(new String(arr[3]));

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    private class Longop extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            loadSomeDummyData();
            return "Executed";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            mdialog.dismiss();

            myListView.setAdapter(new MyArrayAdapter(Sample.this,
                        R.layout.list, id, name, dateofbirth,
                        status));
            }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            mdialog = ProgressDialog.show(Sample.this, "Please wait...",
                    "Retrieving data ...", true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        }
    }



    private class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        // this list hold the data that we will see in listview
        private List<String> myData = new ArrayList<String>();
        private List<String> myData1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        private List<String> myData2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        private List<String> myData3 = new ArrayList<String>();


        public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                List<String> objects, List<String> objects1,
                List<String> objects2, List<String> objects3) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

            context = getContext();

            myData = objects;
            myData1 = objects1;
            myData2 = objects2;
            myData3 = objects3;
            }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            View v = convertView;

            if (v == null) {

                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, null);
                // Log.d(EKSI, "Getting the inflater from the system context");
            }

            String sid = myData.get(position);
            String sname = myData1.get(position);
            String dob = myData2.get(position);
            String sstatus = myData3.get(position);


                TextView entryTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.id1);

                entryTextView.setText(sid);


                TextView entryTextView1 = (TextView) v
                        .findViewById(R.id.id2);
                entryTextView1.setText(sname);


                TextView entryTextView2 = (TextView) v
                        .findViewById(R.id.id3);
                entryTextView2.setText(dob);


                TextView entryTextView3 = (TextView) v
                        .findViewById(R.id.id4);
                entryTextView3.setText(sstatus);

            return v;
        }
    }
```

Comment: have you get answer amrutha.I am also stuck in this..can you help me with this http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/96576/how-to-display-required-data-from-json

Answer (score 0):

You could  also use this lib
https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh.

Answer (score 0):

I implement this function not base ListView that can do this;

- Custom loading view,override [onDraw](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onDraw%28android.graphics.Canvas%29) menthod
- Add loading view at the end of LinearLayout view. When loading view is show, it should call some methods to get data from server by HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to inflate an xml in

```
  lstView.addFooterView(R.layout.footer);
```

and handle onclick of the button residing in footer